# Why is it OK to pass a class to the key attribute of Python's sorted() function?

Tags: python

I came across code something like this and am trying to understand how it works. From the python documentation for sorted() the `key` parameter takes a function which takes a single argument and then returns a key to be used in the comparison. This code is assigning `key` a class. How is this ok? And how does `__lt__` get `x` and `y` passed to it?

```
class K(str):
    def __lt__(x, y):
        return x > y
input = [3, 30, 7]
sorted(input, key=K)
```

Output: `[7, 30, 3]`

Comment: A class is a callable just like a function (the return value is an object of that class)
, and the class defined here takes a single argument. That meets all the requirements of the `key` parameter.

Comment: If `__lt__(x, y)` runs `x < y`, how's that going to be evaluated _without_ calling `__lt__`? So the recursion error should be obvious.

Comment: @larsks the argument `str` seems to have a special meaning as I cannot replace it with just a variable name. Also if it takes 1 argument where are `x` and `y` coming from?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. Feeling foolish. I will edit to remove that part.

Comment: @Reep, `str` is the parent class that `K` is subclassing. The `str` class has a 1-argument constructor that can take an existing string as an argument, so K inherits it and has one too.

Comment: @Reep, ...as for `x` and `y`, they're just argument names to `__lt__`; they could be called _anything_ and still have the same function. Conventionally, the `x` one would be called `self`, and the `y` one might be called `other` -- so it's comparing the current object (`self` -- the string that was passed to the current instance's `__init__`) against another one (`other`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Also this example from the documentation doesn't seem to have the same recursion problem. `>>> Student.__lt__ = lambda self, other: self.age < other.age`

Comment: @Reep, right, your other example doesn't have the problem because it's not comparing the `Student` objects but only comparing their ages; that makes it completely different code.

Comment: Even if it works, that code makes me shudder. Better to use `sorted(input,key = str,reverse = True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python uses duck typing, so it doesn't check if the key is a function, it just calls it. the key argument is used in sorted to determine what to compare. In this case, instead of comparing [3, 30, 7] it's comparing [K(3), K(30), K(7)]. That's also why there's a __lt__ method implemented, for the less than comparison

Comment: It's hard to find any official python doc or tutorial that talks about "duck typing" or about how you can use a function name and class name interchangeably if certain rules are followed. Should be explained somewhere.

Comment: You're missing the point: classes and functions are both "callables": they accept one or more arguments and return a value to the caller. There isn't any sort of special support here for classes vs functions; the `key` parameter will accept any callable.

Comment: No, I get it now. All I am saying is that someone should mention that fact. For eg. this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html doesn't say that you can use classes where you would use functions since they are the same to Python. Then here https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/sorting.html under "Key Functions" you have "The value of the key parameter should be a function that takes a single argument and returns a key to use for sorting purposes." Could have been "should be a callable". Just like you would say "iterable" instead of "list" where appropriate.